# Is Boost endian library platform-independent?

Tags: c++, boost, endianness

There is a valid `uint8_t*` buffer with four `uint8_t` bytes.

I know the buffer contains two `uint16_t` numbers in big-endian format, and I want to extract them.

I can create the required data manually, while taking care of the correct endianness:

```
const std::uint8_t* data = ...
uint16_t first =  (data[1]<<8) + data[0];
uint16_t second = (data[3]<<8) + data[2];
```

I have been told (thanks to @eerorika):

> *this* works the same way on all systems. This reads the data as little
>   endian, whether the CPU is little, big or some other endian. This is
>   well portable.

And this works as intended.

Now let's consider another solution with Boost's endian library:

```
struct datatype {
    boost::endian::little_int16_buf_t     first;
    boost::endian::little_int16_buf_t     second;
} d;

memcpy(&d, data, sizeof d);
```

This solution also works, and my question is: *is this in any way worse in terms of portability, platform- and CPU-dependency than the first?*

If I compile and run this on a non little-endian architecture, will it produce the same values as on a little-endian one?

Comment: It would be a pretty useless library if it wasn't portable.

Comment: I think better way to express the question is: Is this a correct way to use the library.

Comment: The first seems valid only for *little* endian input, but OK for big and little endian systems, since it is mathematically going to make them into the local endian integer.  The internet stuff has big endian extraction calls, as IP is big endian.

The second looks very nice and portable as described for the first.  A copy should not be needed; you can just cast and use the original storage.

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett Casting and using the original storage would unfortunately be a violation of the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: From what I read, assuming the types are incompatible, if you make a union of the two types, you can cast your rvalue's pointer to a pointer to the union and access the alternative type through it, so using the original storage.

Comment: I think the union method is only valid for C, and not for C++ but I might misunderstood something.